# Angular service returning and html file instead of a json file

Tags: json, angularjs, angular-services, mean-stack

I've been learning MEAN stack technologies for a week now. I'm having a problem using a custom service in Angular. I try to get a .json file, but when the app loads & I examine the loaded resources in the web inspector, the ison file is showing the code from my index.html file. Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

This is the custom service:

```
    angular.module('StudentService', [])
        .factory('Students', ['$http', function($http) {
        return $http.get('app/students.json');
    }]);
```

I don't understand how it could be loaded with the title 'students.json' but show up in the web inspector as html code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: in your express app, you probably have to add the route you are using for json to load, to static routes

Comment: Thanks! I think I had different routes in my express vs. my custom service. It's a little embarrassing, but at least that problem is taken care of.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this

```
 $http.get('app/students.json')
       .then(function(res){
          $scope.todos = res.data;                
        });
return $scope.todos;
```